# Is it possible to force TeamCity to create one build for each SVN commit?

Tags: c#, svn, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have the follow configuration in my TeamCity:

- 2 Projects and each project some build configurations

My problem is that whenever TeamCity is building a project and a new Tag is created 
(e.g: Tag-5.9.0 revision 533) this tag goes to the “Pending” list.  If another Tag is created (e.g: Tag-5.9.1 revision 539) I have now the two Tag’s in the Pending list.

What happens is that TeamCity will always compile the newest Tag.

My output Folder was supposed to contain the follow folders:

- C:\Deploy\Client\Version\Tag-5.9.0-rev.533
- C:\Deploy\Client\Version\Tag-5.9.1-rev.539

However I have just the last committed Tag.

- C:\Deploy\Client\Version\Tag-5.9.1-rev.539

Is there a way to force an individual build for each commit ??

Thanks,

---

TeamCity Version 6.5.1 (build 17834)

Comment: Are you running afoul of the Quiet Period in your Build Trigger?

Comment: Take a look at build triggers in your project's configuration. It's absolutely possible.

Comment: In addition to my prevoius comment, take a look here: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Configuring+VCS+Triggers

Comment: Hello, I take a look into both configuration it's means, Quite Period and Build Trigger. But don't I got always the same result. 

-All Commits that is in the Pending list will create just one build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not implemented as answed by JetBrains developper, you can check my post to [JetBrains Developer](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/311491?tstart=0), however have some workarounds for this.

Thanks.